# Rerender functional component when prop changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming

I'm having trouble rerendering component when parent state passed to child component changes. *MapNav* component contains buttons which triggers methods changing current displayed popup. My problem is to re-render UserPopup button when someone clicks *zaloguj* or *wyloguj*, it should work but it does not and i cant figure out what is wrong also i don't want to trigger animation when *isLoggedIn* state changes and one more thing logIn method changes state properly. *isLoggedIn* state is just temporary later i'll change that to use store instead. I'm trying to write as much functional component but in some cases i cant avoid using state and i bet that there are issues in my code so i'll appreciate all improvement tips.

```js
const MapNav = (props) => {
  return       <div className={'mapNavContainer'}>
        <ul className={'navList'}>
          <li><a href="#about"><i className={"glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen"} /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#about"><i className={"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"} /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#about"><i className={"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"} /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#about"><i className={"glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"} /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onClick={props.onUserIconClick}><i className={"glyphicon glyphicon-user"} /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onClick={props.onInfoClick}><i className={"glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"} /></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
}

const UserPopup = (props) => {
  return <div>
    {(props.isLoggedIn) ? (
      <div className={'navPopups col-sm-3 panel panel-default'}>
        <div className={"panel-heading"}>Zalogowany</div>
        <div className={"panel-body"}>
          <button type='submit' onClick={props.logIn}>wyloguj</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      ) : (
        <div className={'navPopups col-sm-3 panel panel-default'}>
          <div className={"panel-heading"}>Niezalogowany</div>
          <div className={"panel-body"}>
            <button type='submit' onClick={props.logIn}>Zaloguj</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  </div>;
};

function Welcome(props) {
  return <div className={'navPopups col-sm-3 panel panel-default'}>
    <div className={"panel-heading"}>Informacje o Autorze.</div>
    <div className={"panel-body"}>
        Basic panel example
    </div>
  </div>;
}

class MapHeader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentPopup: null,
      isLoggedIn: false,
      username: 'gregorowicz.k@gmail.com',
    };

    this.onInfoClick = this.onInfoClick.bind(this);
    this.onUserIconClick = this.onUserIconClick.bind(this);
    this.logIn = this.logIn.bind(this);
  }

  onInfoClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setPopup(<Welcome />);
  }

  onUserIconClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const loginPopup = <UserPopup isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn} username={this.state.username} logIn={this.logIn} />;
    this.setPopup(loginPopup);
  }

  setPopup = (obj) => {
    this.state.currentPopup === null ? this.setState({ currentPopup: obj }) : this.setState({ currentPopup: null });
  }

  logIn = (e) => {
    this.setState({ isLoggedIn: !this.state.isLoggedIn });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <nav className={'header'}>
        <div className={'container-fluid'}>
          <div className={"navbar-header"}>
            <button type="button" className={"navbar-toggle collapsed"} data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span className={"sr-only"}>Toggle navigation</span>
              <span className={"icon-bar"} />
              <span className={"icon-bar"} />
              <span className={"icon-bar"} />
            </button>
          </div>

          <div id={"navbar"} className={'navContainer'}>
            {MapNav({onInfoClick:this.onInfoClick, onUserIconClick:this.onUserIconClick})}
    {this.state.currentPopup ? this.state.currentPopup : null}
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    )
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <MapHeader />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Comment: Side note: `className={"panel-heading"}` can more simply be written `className="panel-heading"`. There's no need for `{}` when the value is a simple string.

Comment: Thank you for tip also i've added runnable

Comment: Side note 2: Your `logIn` and such are arrow functions that close over `this`. Calling `bind` on them won't do anything to change their `this` (but it's already correct, so you don't need `bind`).

Comment: To make the problem happen click user icon (second icon from bottom) then click zaloguj after that isLoggedIn state chages but it does not rerendering UserPopup, as it should display different button and panel heading based on passed isLoggedIn prop.

Comment: When *zaloguj* button is clicked state in parent component *MapHeader* is changed properly, so to fully understand what my problem is click user icon > click *zaloguj* and then click user icon two times. As you will see, different popup shows up so isLoggedIn is changed, but it does not trigger rerendering instantly, UserPopup have  to be destroyed and created again to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. There is currentPopup state in my code which stored current popup displayed, to see changes i had to unmount and mount component again after isLogggedIn state changed, so i've changed the way to display current popup. Instead storing whole component in state, i store just simple string values which provide information about current component. Anyway thank you for tips, i'll surely apply them in my code.

```js
const MapNav = (props) => {
  return       <div className={'mapNavContainer'}>
        <ul className={'navList'}>
          <li><a href="#about"><i className={"glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen"} /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#about"><i className={"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"} /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#about"><i className={"glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"} /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#about"><i className={"glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"} /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onClick={props.onUserIconClick}><i className={"glyphicon glyphicon-user"} /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onClick={props.onInfoClick}><i className={"glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"} /></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
}

const UserPopup = (props) => {
  return <div>
    {(props.isLoggedIn) ? (
      <div className={'navPopups col-sm-3 panel panel-default'}>
        <div className={"panel-heading"}>Zalogowany</div>
        <div className={"panel-body"}>
          <button type='submit' onClick={props.logIn}>wyloguj</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      ) : (
        <div className={'navPopups col-sm-3 panel panel-default'}>
          <div className={"panel-heading"}>Niezalogowany</div>
          <div className={"panel-body"}>
            <button type='submit' onClick={props.logIn}>Zaloguj</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  </div>;
};

function Welcome(props) {
  return <div className={'navPopups col-sm-3 panel panel-default'}>
    <div className={"panel-heading"}>Informacje o Autorze.</div>
    <div className={"panel-body"}>
        Basic panel example
    </div>
  </div>;
}

class MapHeader extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentPopup: null,
      isLoggedIn: null,
    };

    this.onInfoClick = this.onInfoClick.bind(this);
    this.onUserIconClick = this.onUserIconClick.bind(this);
    this.logIn = this.logIn.bind(this);
  }
                  
  onInfoClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ currentPopup: this.state.currentPopup === 'info' ? null : 'info' });
  }
    
  onUserIconClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ currentPopup: this.state.currentPopup === 'user_login' ? null : 'user_login' });
  }

  setPopup = (obj) => {
    this.setState({ currentPopup: this.state.currentPopup === 'user_login' ? null : 'user_login' });
  }

  logIn = (e) => {
    this.setState({ isLoggedIn: !this.state.isLoggedIn });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <nav className={'header'}>
        <div className={'container-fluid'}>
          <div className={"navbar-header"}>
            <button type="button" className={"navbar-toggle collapsed"} data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span className={"sr-only"}>Toggle navigation</span>
              <span className={"icon-bar"} />
              <span className={"icon-bar"} />
              <span className={"icon-bar"} />
            </button>
          </div>

          <div id={"navbar"} className={'navContainer'}>
            {MapNav({onInfoClick:this.onInfoClick, onUserIconClick:this.onUserIconClick})}

              {this.state.currentPopup === 'info' ? <Welcome /> : null}
              {this.state.currentPopup === 'user_login' ? (
                <UserPopup isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn} logIn={this.logIn} />
              ) : null}

          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    )
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <MapHeader />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```